# Stepper driver 3.3V 3A

Tags: driver, stepper-motor, h-bridge

(Edited text 15:53--05/1-2017)

I got these two steppers for my home project, and thought that I just needed a H-bridge and then I am good, until I found that either I am misunderstanding these ratings, or I have a special stepping engine.
[Stepper](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1996055.pdf?_ga=1.9938613.1686970633.1480937778) It has data 3.3V and 3A. and it is a 4 wired Bipolar

The idea was to have an arduino with 4 sensors that would make a "scan" every 1 or 2. hour. Then the arduino shuld tell 1 step motor to turn left/right and another motor to go up/down, so the sun panels would get most out of the sun.

So, looked at WWW to get some ideas on what chip to use, and most recommended the L293D and then i got stuck. then i wrote a post in here and now im super confused hehe.. (so i edited this text to clarify my thoughts and what is my end goal, and how)

I have a 12V battery as a supply! But I just step that down.

The L293D, or SN754410, require 5V or more, or have less then 3A current. (the steppers was 3.3V 3A)

Q.
Am I misunderstanding something, or am I just blind?

Q. Can any help me design a schematic for my own bridge for driving 2 steppers, if there really ain't any out there in the world?

A. I wont just buy one of them already done prints [(example)](https://www.pololu.com/product/2970). I just need the chip, or help designing my own bridge, that can drive 2 steppers 3.3V 3A

Comment: "All recommend" - who is this "all" you talk about?

Comment: Stepper Driver and not an H-bridge.  You are not making the difference between DC motors and Stepper Motors here.

Comment: What i mean when i say "all" is. every site iv'e been at, to get some know how, talk bout L293D as the most common chip (as they write). But that said, all guides is having at is with an arduino as the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The L298 H-bridge can handle 4A DC total if using both channels in constant operation. Your stepper will use 3A intermittently on each channel, which the device should be able to handle according to the datasheet. <s>If you are using a programmable microcontroller such as an Arduino, you can also reduce the stepping frequency to reduce the current through the H-bridge chip</s>. You should also attach a heat sink to the chip. Note that you need to add ultra fast recovery diodes (or just fast recovery) to reduce back-EMF.

As for the power issues, I recommend using voltage regulators, such as the L7805 or equivalent with filter capacitors for your 5V and 3.3V.

Here is a link to an instructable which shows you how to make your own stepper driver to use with arduino: http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Arduino-Motor-Shield-L298N-Chip-2-4-Amps-/

If you would rather not use a microcontroller, here is a tutorial for building a stepper driver circuit that uses a 555 timer circuit instead:

http://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/stepper-motor-driver

Edit: You can't control the current through a stepper by adjusting the frequency. A Chopper drive is what you need, and it can be run at several times the rated voltage of the stepper (See bottom of the linked page):

https://learn.adafruit.com/all-about-stepper-motors/matching-the-driver-to-the-stepper

Comment: How does lower frequency reduce current? Usually it works the opposite way...

Comment: The enable pins of the L298 allow you to completely cut off the current through each coil momentarily. Between steps you could add a tiny delay that reduces the average current through the coils by disabling both channels.

Comment: You can't disable during motion. You can't eve always disable when not in motion. Locking a motor in certain position is a feature. What if his solar panel will fall down when he disables?

Comment: Did some research and found that you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Voltage may be just fine, don't worry about it. But you don't need H-Bridge, you need a stepper driver, similar to DRV8811 or something else, that will limit/control the current and perform steps. To make it by yourself you need a whole project...

While waiting for reply, i want to add something. The voltage doesn't matter much in theory. What depends on voltage (very roughly) is how fast you can go, because the BEMF. But it also depends on you steps profile, etc. In the end, if you will be able to move on exact speed of 3.3V, the mean voltage on phases will be 3.3V. Also i wouldn't be afraid of arcing- it's 12V, what damage could it cause?

If you use DRV8811, voltage will also affect current control circuit. But if you are aware of it during design- it's not a problem.

I am absolutely bored while code is compiling, so i want to add one more comment about BEMF. Usually motor is rated for certain working point. They will say: 1000RPM, 17V, 2A, 20W, etc. RPM is important, but if they take a nice number there, any other number will usually not be round and nice. But 3.3V is nice! That means, probably, it's just a general guidline, meaning nothing special. You will not want to use it with 300V, but 5V, 12V, 24V will all be OK, as long as you don't exceed current and power rating. Both may cause damage.

Comment: I can add, that the steppers are for turning an X, Y for an solar tracker. 
 So the main brain will be an arduino, that will read, and give signal out to the steppers.
 so speed really aint the focus for me.
I was just stuck in H-bridge as all www sides i had been to was giving them as examples.

Comment: It's cool, but signals are to the motor driver, not the motor itself. So you need in the middle some kind of "amplifier", like DRV8811

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should consider is the fact that you think you may be able to drive a stepper motor with an H-bridge.  This is not going to work.  You will need to either build a circuit to drive the stepper motor or get a stepper motor driver chip.  This driver chip will help you drive the stepper motor.

Also, is your motor a unipolar or bipolar stepper?  This will make a small difference when it comes to choose the driver chip.  And finally, how are you trying to drive the stepper motor?  You can either use "wave drive", "full-step drive", or "half-stepping".  Below is a picture of how you may want to drive your stepper motor.

[image]

Ultimately, you will want to have two driver chips to drive these two motors.  Or maybe, there are chips out there that have enough pins to drive two motors at the same time.  If you can provide more information how you plan to use the motors, I can provide more information on how to implement the appropriate circuit.